# Is it possible to follow precisely movement of a smartphone in app?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

Is there any way to make this kind of app:
you draw a room with precision in the program, put your actual position(where is your phone right now) point in this representation of your room in the app and then when your phone is moving the app would say precisely where it is in the room?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have issues with most phones because the GPS isn't going to give you a fine enough location for what your trying.

http://www.mio.com/technology-gps-accuracy.htm

Comment: I actually wanted to use sensors like accelerometer. Is it possible?

Comment: You can try looking through this, but I am unsure if you need a gyroscope for it or not: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4983/how-to-determine-position-from-gyroscope-and-accelerometer-input